# Typo 3 installation ended with URL Not Found

Tags: content-management-system, typo3

I installed Typo 3 version 4.7.2 and in the last step I selected the example system called "Introduction package" (not the "Blank" one). After clicking "Go to your website" it redirected me to URL `BASE/get-started/` which said:

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL BASE/index.php was not found on this server.

Can you please help me?

Comment: In the BackEnd your first site is redirection into other, check where is this redirecting to.

Comment: which url was the install-tool url, which redirect would you expect? just try: BASE/index.php (you should see a website) or BASE/typo3/ (you should see the TYPO3 Login). check if mod_rewrite is active!

Comment: thanks @maholtz, I found a solution already (posted it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution. It was little confusing because in `.htaccess` they say

```
# For httpd.conf, use this line instead of the next one:
# RewriteRule ^/TYPO3root/<...>
RewriteRule ^<...>
```

So despite of using .htaccess I uncommented the lines with TYPO3root, which were said to be used in `httpd.conf`, replaced TYPO3root with actual value and that's it.

Not only it should work out-of-the-box without changing the .htaccess but also the comments are confusing.

Comment: I don't remember how's Introduction Package is working, but believe that in source+dummy package .htaccess is correct

Comment: What is the path to .htaccess file where we have to modify above? There are .htaccess files in many folders.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know in 4.7.2, but in 6.1.7 you can find a file called `_.htaccess` that you can copy as `.htaccess` in your web root.