# Typo 3 login Not Found The requested URL was not found on this server

Tags: apache

I'm new to typo3.
After installation and after login to admin I keep getting

```
Not Found 
The requested URL was not found on this server.
```

I've seen the solution on [Typo 3 installation ended with URL Not Found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11348804/typo-3-installation-ended-with-url-not-found) but can't figure out which .htaccess file to modify. There are many .htaccess files.

I'm facing not found error on both front end and admin. I've installed latest version.

I installed typo3 by following instructions here

https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/tutorial-getting-started/11.5/en-us/Installation/Install.html#install

Comment: How did you setup TYPO3? composer? Did you use the Installer Tool?

Comment: This guide https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/tutorial-getting-started/11.5/en-us/Installation/Install.html#install

Comment: You can find the correct .htaccess in `<docroot>/typo3/sysext/install/Resources/Private/FolderStructureTemplateFiles/root-htaccess`. But normally it should be copied on installation setup.

Comment: I did, it didn't work, I think it is the virtual host settings. There is no instructions on how to set it up on they just wrote "After you have configured your web server to point ot the public directory of your project, TYPO3 can be accessed via a web browser. When accessing a new site for the first time, TYPO3 automatically redirects all requests to /typo3/install.php to complete the installation process."

Comment: It only needs a default web server like Nginx or Apache. Where is your document root pointing to?

Comment: My local install is this http://localhost/typo3/typo/public/typo3/install.php I install it and then afterwards it goes to Not found page. http://localhost/typo3/typo/public/typo3/login - not found. I can see there is already a .htaccess file under public folder which looks exactly same as the one on <docroot>/typo3/sysext/install/Resources/Private/FolderStructureTemplateFiles/root-htaccess. I did copy the above .htaccess to public folder but I'm seeing same error.

Comment: First you should login to the backend. This should be in your case localhost/typo3/typo/public/typo3/ (without login)

Comment: I did that already, after login it goes to http://localhost/typo3/typo/public/typo3/login?loginProvider=1433416747 and gives not found.

Comment: Then there must be a config issue regarding web server or your local setup. Can't help you with the information you gave me yet..

Comment: In your link there is always a "login" at the end. Please try it without "login". There is no "login" folder or file inside TYPO3.

Comment: I don't add login, typo3 automatically does that. I go here http://localhost/typo3/typo/public/typo3/ enter login and password, it redirects to http://localhost/typo3/typo/public/typo3/login?loginProvider=1433416747 after login

Comment: Are you sure your Apache web server handles the .htaccess file? There are options to ignore them. Your issue sounds like the .htaccess issue.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. There was issue with apache config file. I've posted solution below.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @thomas-löffler for pointing it out.

It turns out that there was issue with apache configuration. The solution is to add following in httpd.conf

```
AllowOverride All
       Order deny,allow
       Allow from all
```

Don't forget to restart apache afterwards.

```
$sudo vi /etc/apache2/httpd.conf

....
DocumentRoot "/Users/imac/ROOT/WebRoot"
<Directory "/Users/imac/ROOT/WebRoot">
    #   
    # Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
    # or any combination of: 
    #   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
    #   
    # Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
    # doesn't give it to you.
    #   
    # The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see 
    # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#options
    # for more information.
    #   
    Options FollowSymLinks Multiviews
    MultiviewsMatch Any 

    #   
    # AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
    # It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
    #   AllowOverride FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
    #   
    #AllowOverride None
       
    AllowOverride All 
       Order deny,allow
       Allow from all 

    #   
    # Controls who can get stuff from this server.
    #
    Require all granted
</Directory>
......
```